# How to get a matplotlib plot with labels at both ends of the curves?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to replicate this plot available [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/1) with the data available [here](https://github.com/robjhyndman/fpp2-package/blob/master/data/a10.rda).

[image: seasonal]

I have been able to get this far which is kind of messy to say the least.

[image]

The code used to get the above messy plot is this:

```
def season_plot():
#robjects.r['load']("./data/a10.rda")
#print(robjects.r['a10'])
#pandas2ri.activate()
#pydf = pd.DataFrame(robjects.r['a10'])
pydf = pd.read_csv('./data/a10.csv',header=None,names=['date','drug_sales'])
dtrng = pd.date_range("1991-07","2008-06",freq='MS')
pydf.set_index(dtrng, inplace=True)
pydf.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
#print(pydf.tail())
pv = pd.pivot_table(pydf,
                index=pydf.index.month,
                columns=pydf.index.year,
                values='drug_sales',
                aggfunc='sum')
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
pv.plot(ax=ax,style='o-',legend=None)
#ax.margins(x=0.15)
for line, name in zip(ax.lines, pv.columns):
    first = line.get_ydata()[0]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(0,first), xytext=(0,0),
                color=line.get_color(),
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
                textcoords="offset points",
                size=10, va="center")
for line, name in zip(ax.lines, pv.columns):
    last = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(1,last), xytext=(0,0),
                color=line.get_color(),
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
                textcoords="offset points",
                size=10, va="center")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(13))
xtks = ax.get_xticks().tolist()
xlabels = [calendar.month_abbr[int(x)] if x in range(1,13) else x \
           for x in xtks]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
plt.title('Antidiabetic drug sales')
plt.ylabel('$ million')
plt.show()
```

How do I get to align the year labels neatly at the exact locations depicted in the first plot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug these kind of problems without some example data. That being said, to me, there seem to be two problems:

1) your x-values for the variable `xy` in `annotate` seem incorrect, at least for the endpoint. `xy` for the end-point should be something like `xy = line.get_xdata[-1], line.get_ydata[-1]`; ditto for the start although your guestimate of `0` for the x-value is probably correct.

2) If your don't want the label to overlap the data, then you should set your offset points to something other than `xytext=(0,0)`. `(-5,0)` and `(5,0)` should look fine, if you set your `horizontalalignment` to `'right'` and `'left'` for your startpoint and endpoint, respectively.

Comment: I have given a link to the data which unfortunately is in R data format. The plot needs space between the xdata points corresponding to 'Jan' and left y-axis as well as between xdata points corresponding to 'Dec' and right y-axis. How do I get that space to fit in the labels?

Comment: The simplest way would be to set the x-limits explicitly to something like `ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 1.1)`.

Comment: I have tired the first two suggestions before posting. They help but not substantially. set_xlim distorts the whole plot.

Comment: "distorts the whole plot" is not precise enough for me or anybody else to debug the problem. If you do want more help on this, I suggest that you update the figures and export your pandas dataframe to csv (`write_to_csv`, IIRC) and upload it somewhere accessible. Expecting people to figure out how to read in an R binary data blob (which frankly might contain anything and is hence a substantial security risk) is a bit much to ask on SO, IMHO.